# How to differentiate the distribution function of lognormal distribution with respect to its parameters?

Tags: lognormal-distribution, calculus

How to differentiate the distribution function of lognormal distribution with respect to its parameters? What solution will we get? I know if differentiate wrt variable, we will get density function.!

[image]

Comment: Please present your notation. For the standard notation you will find the equations [at mathworld.wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogNormalDistribution.html).

Comment: @Semoi yes I have added now..Sorry i dont know how to write equations in this page.. so I have uploaded image of equations.

Comment: @Huchesh what is the context for your question?

Comment: @phdmba7of12 actually i am using truncated lognormal distribution (TLD). In truncated distribution (density of the distribution divided by the distribution function of the distribution at the specific point) , denominator is distribution function which is in the form of cumulative distribution function in case of lognormal distribution. And i want to estimate the parameters of the LTD but due to the not explicit form of likelihood equations (LE's), i have to use numerical methods like newton raphson method. In NR method, i have to take the derivatives of LE's. conti..

Comment: @phdmba7of12 So i am unable to differentiate that distribution function with respect to parameters. I hope, u got my point.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you stated the cumulative distribution function is
$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(z) dz = \Phi\big[\frac{\ln(x)-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\big]$$

Now I would differentiate the error fct using the *chain rule*
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Phi[z] = \frac{\partial \Phi[z]}{\partial z} \cdot \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = f(z) \cdot \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$ 
So all you need to do is to calculate the partial derivatives
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial }{\partial \mu} \big[\frac{\ln(x)-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\big] &= ... \\
\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma} \big[\frac{\ln(x)-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\big] &= ... 
\end{align}
which is straight forward.

Comment: can u do in detail please??

Comment: what second order differentiation of the above equations??

Comment: Well, $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} \mu = 1$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} \sigma^{-1} = -\sigma^{-2}$.

Comment: I am asking what is second order differentiation of distribution function with respect to parameters? I have mentioned one of above comments why am doing this.? Using the Newton Raphson method, i am estimating the parameters so i have to form a hassian matrix which second order derivative matrix.

Comment: logl=-Nlog σ\left(2πright)-∑i filog xi-0.5∑ifn fi eft((log xi-μ/σ2right)-Nlog Φ eft((log T-μ/σright)

Comment: Could you explain where the factor of $1/\sqrt{2}$ comes from and what "$y$" represents?